# Applying a function (mkString) to an entire column in Spark dataframe, error if column name has "."

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm attempting to apply a function over a column of a Spark dataframe in Scala. The column is a String type, and I'd like to concatenate each token in the string with an "_" delimiter (e.g. "A B" --> "A_B"). I'm doing this with:

```
val converter: (String => String) = (arg: String) => {arg.split(" ").mkString("_")}
val myUDF = udf(converter)
val newDF = oldDF
  .withColumn("TEST", myUDF(oldDF("colA.B")) )
display(newDF)
```

This works for columns in the dataframe with names without a dot ("."). However, the dot in the column name "colA.B" seems to be breaking the code and throws the error:

```
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "colA.B" among (colA.B, col1, col2);
```

I suppose a work around would be to rename the column (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359539/accessing-column-names-with-periods-spark-sql-1-3)), but I'd prefer not to do this.

Comment: pls [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359539/accessing-column-names-with-periods-spark-sql-1-3)

Comment: probably you are facing this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15230) seems like its fixed in 2.0 which version of spark you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6.2 because df.map(row=>...) doesn't seem to work on Spark 2.0. I'm sure it does, but I'm using 1.6.2 until I can figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with back quotes like below example ([source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17024))

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("user1", "task1"),
  ("user2", "task2")
)).toDF("user", "user.task")
df.select(df("user"), df("`user.task`")).show()


+-----+---------+
| user|user.task|
+-----+---------+
|user1|    task1|
|user2|    task2|
+-----+---------+
```

In your case before applying function you need to back quote such column...