How to read json column with dot in it in scala?
I want to read json a column which has dot(.) in it. Below code works fine it there is no dot.
val data = """{
"abc.id": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "UNKNOWN"
}]}""";

   
val inputdata = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data :: Nil);
val inputDF = spark.read.json(inputdata);
inputDF.show();
inputDF.select(inputDF.columns.map(c => col(c)(0).as(c)): _*).show()


Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359539/accessing-column-names-with-periods-spark-sql-1-3/58183005#58183005

Does this answer your question? Accessing column names with periods - Spark SQL 1.3

Use backtick (`) when you have special characters in columns.
val data = """{
"abc.id": [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "UNKNOWN"
}]}"""

val inputdata = Seq(data).toDS

val df = spark.read.json(inputdata);

df
.select(inputDF.columns.map(c => col(s"`${c}`")(0).as(c)):_*)
.show(false)

+--------------+
|abc.id        |
+--------------+
|{123, UNKNOWN}|
+--------------+

